# Batch script to Rename files if exists

Tags: batch-file

I was trying to write a batch script to rename files in a folder. 
I am using **multiple/nested** if exist command in the batch script. I am getting **syntax error** while executing the script.
Below is the batch script I am using.

```
IF EXIST "C:\Test\config.xml_QA" 
(
  IF EXIST "C:\Test\config.xml" 
    (

            REN C:\Test\config.xml config.xml_ST
        REN C:\Test\config.xml_QA  config.xml
    )
) 

ELSE IF EXIST "C:\Test\config.xml_ST"
(
    IF EXIST "C:\Test\config.xml"
    (
        REN C:\Test\config.xml config.xml_QA
        REN C:\Test\config.xml_ST  config.xml
    )
)
```

Here I want the batch script to do is, rename **config.xml_QA** to **config.xml** and **config.xml** to **config.xml_st** only if both the **config.xml_QA** and **config.xml** are present in the folder.

Hoping to get the correct answers for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The syntactically correct format for IF/ELSE in batch is:

```
   IF ...CONDITION... (
   ) ELSE (
   )
```

You need to put the braces on the same line as the `IF` and `ELSE` tokens.

Comment: @MCND You're right of course.  I think I got confused with a potential "ELSEIF". Thanks.